# Converting some text within an element to an element itself using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is this possible using JavaScript or JQuery, or anything else?

Say I have an HTML file like this

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

And I want to turn "World" into a span element itself, like so (so that I can style just "World")

```
<div>
    <p>Hello <span>World</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you always know what the particular text will be, around which you want to add the span tag?

Comment: I have added the answer assuming that you already know the word, please accept the answer if that's what you were looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are a lot of unknowns in your question, so I am assuming that you already know the string/word around which you want to add the html tag.

So keeping that in mind, following solution should work:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="my-text">Hello World, Again!</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    const stringToBeReplaced = "World"; // what you want to replace
    const innerText = document.getElementById("my-text").innerText; //grab the text
    const beginIndex = innerText.indexOf(stringToBeReplaced); // get text where string begins

    // if string exists
    if (beginIndex >= 0) {
    const textWithTag =
              "<span style='color: red'>" + stringToBeReplaced + "</span>";
    const newString = innerText.replace(stringToBeReplaced, textWithTag);
    // replace the text with new string
    document.getElementById("my-text").innerHTML = newString;
   }
```

Hope this is what you were asking and looking for.

Comment: Man, I was close. I tried replacing stringToBeReplaced with an element I created using createElement()... I could have been more clear, sorry about that. And thank you for the help!

Comment: Yeah that could also work, but it is just that I am trying to re-use `stringToBeReplaced ` everywhere, feel free to modify this as you want. And no worries, I know we've all been there where we just hit the dead end, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace3

str.replace solves the job.  The comment of @Umer Hassan is correct.